# validate integer value in mule 3 dataweave 1.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-component

I want to validate the field value as integer and make the test value as integer. In below code if the field value is string then I am getting error. Here I need to configure like if the value is not integer then make the test value is "" .

```
        %dw 1.0
        %output application/json
        %var field="2312321a"
        %function isEmpty(value) (value!=null and value!="")
        ---
        {
            test: field as :number as :string {format: "###"} as :number when isEmpty(field) otherwise ""
        }
```

expected: eg: 123.44--> 123, 1234-> 1234, 123ab-> "", "" -> ""

Comment: Do you mean if the field is a String of numbers then you are trying to convert it to number. If it is alphanumeric, you want a blank string?

Comment: if the value is string then make it blank or "". if value is numeric or float then make it integer and send the value. eg: 123.44--> 123, 1234-> 1234, 123ab-> "", "" -> ""

Comment: Answer this, if `%var field="123"` then output should be `123`, correct?

Comment: yes correct. but in case if field value is coming as string then it should return null or "" value

Comment: You are getting confused with what string is. `"abc"` is a string and `"1"` is also a string. `1` is a Number (notice is it not wrapped in quotes). What you need is if the string represents a numeric value, then you want the string as Number, if it contains any other characters then you want a blank string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to verify if a string contains only numeric values. This is a regex you can use for this purpose. It will handle negative values too.

> /[+-]?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)/

And use [`matches`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/1.2/dataweave-operators#matches) to check if the string is numeric or not.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var field="2312321a"
%function isNumeric(string) string matches /[+-]?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)/
---
{
    test: field as :number as :string{format: "###"} as :number when isNumeric(field) otherwise ""
}
```